# Convergent sequence on a step function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm not quite sure how to go about proving this:

*Let $\phi:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a step function and $s \in (a,b)$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $[a,b]$ with each $x_n > s$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=s$. Prove that the sequence $(\phi(x_n))$ converges.*

I was thinking that eventually $\phi(x_n)$ must be constant as it would settle on some value that step function takes, but what about if there were a discontinuity at $s$ and the step function jumps? (This is me supposing $(\phi(x_n))$ converges to $\phi(s))$ which I don't know!)

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ be intervals covering $[a,b]$ on which $\phi$ is constant, ordered so that every element of $I_i$ is less than every element of $I_j$ if $i<j$. This is always possible for a step function.

We have three cases to consider. First, $s$ is in the interior of some $I_i$. Then for sufficiently large $n$ we have $n\in I_i$ as well, so $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \phi(x_n)=\phi(s)$. Second, $s$ is the minimum of some $I_i$. Then once again $x_n\in I_i$ for sufficiently large $n$ so $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \phi(x_n)=\phi(s)$. Third, $s$ is the maximum of some $I_i$. Then for sufficiently large $n$ we have $x_n\in I_{i+1}$ and so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \phi(x_n)=\phi(I_{i+1})$.